# How can I turn comments in listings automatically into footnotes?

Tags: listings, footnotes, comments

Is it possible to automatically detect and convert comments in listings into footnotes?

Comment: Are you talking about latex comments or comments in the code being displayed using listings? Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm talking about turning code comments into latex footnotes

Comment: OK, but you should give more details about what you want and show what you have tried!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[paperheight=13cm]{geometry}% for display purposes only

\begingroup\catcode`\^^M\active%
\gdef\gatherfootnote #1^^M{\footnote{#1}^^M}\endgroup

\lstset{language=python,escapeinside={\%}{\^^M},
        escapebegin={\gatherfootnote},
        escapeend={},numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny}


\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    for i in range(4): % a simple python for-loop
       print(i)
       print(2*i)
       print(3*i)
       print(4*i)% this is a code comment
       print(5*i)
       print(6*i)
       print(7*i)% and one more code comment
       print(8*i)
  \end{lstlisting}
Another code listing:
  \begin{lstlisting}
    for j in range(4): % fourth footnote 
       print(j)
       print(2*j)
       print(3*j)
       print(4*j)% fifth footnote
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this approach does not allow multi-line comments: each comment on a line created its own footnote. Note also that the the spaces before the `%` naturally show in the output.